# Multiple serious delays wiring money to the US from Singapore

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, wire-transfer, singapore

I have encountered a number of difficulties wiring money to a relative studying in the US. I have used DBS Singapore, POSB and Maybank Singapore to wire money, but have encountered multiple delays that have lasted in excess of 4 weeks. This is a common occurrence and complaining to bank management has done little to help this matter. I have also complained to MAS in Singapore about this, but was led in a circle and was ultimately told to complain to the banks management, which has not had any result.

I need a way to reliably send money or failing that a way to get the banks to start sending money reliably. Solutions?

Comment: Have you considered money transfer services?

Comment: Yes, but they are both expensive and cannot deposit funds into a bank account. This makes it problematic to do stuff like pay my relative's school fees or rent. With that said, it is something that I have been using because the delays make using the banks unreliable.